# good way to clone JSONObject on Android

Tags: android, json, clone

I have to clone a JSONObject on Android. I am aware of the easy way:

```
JSONObject clone = new JSONObject(original.toString());
```

but somehow it feels wrong/slow to do it this way. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809884/322642 , but on Android I do not have JSONObject.getNames - anyone has a good pointer on how to do this?

Comment: you have the `names` method that returns a JSONArray of names. I agree, there is a bit of overhead, but it should work.

Comment: Is new JSONObject(String) slow/wrong way to create JSONObject?

Comment: @KanakSony nothing wrong. the string is just parsed

Comment: @blackbelt, than how it can be slower or a wrong way, as only String is being cloned from older reference to new object like new JSONObject(new String(String))?

Comment: @KanakSony, it would be simple if you take a look to the source code. [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29), for instance.

Comment: It is not new JSONObject(String) that is the problem. Mainly the fact to go over a string-representation to clone a object is what bothers me. So you have to serialize and deserialize to clone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 2):

the fastest + minimal way I found is this. it does deep copy.

```
JSONObject clone= new JSONObject(original.toMap());
```

Update:
as per Marcos's comment the toMap() function is not available in Android. but the org.json library available on maven under groupId org.json  has it:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.json/json/20210307/bundle

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
public JSONObject shallowCopy(JSONObject original) {
    JSONObject copy = new JSONObject();

    for ( Iterator<String> iterator = original.keys(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String      key     = iterator.next();
        JSONObject  value   = original.optJSONObject(key);

        try {
            copy.put(key, value);
        } catch ( JSONException e ) {
            //TODO process exception
        }
    }

    return copy;
}
```

But remember it is not deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is inefficient, requiring the object to be serialized, and then for the String to be re-parsed.

The simplest, most performant solution is:

```
JSONObject copy = new JSONObject();
for (Object key : original.keySet()) {
  Object value = original.get(key);
  copy.put(key, value);
}
```

> Note: This is a only a **shallow** copy

Comment: Also, this is a shallow copy only for the upper-level keys. If there are some nested JSON objects, they will be left attached still.

Comment: `shallow copy` already specifies that only the top layer gets copied

Comment: Unsure about it: [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shallow_copy), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy)

Comment: Update: yes, @Gibolt, I think you are correct. My misconception was that in a shallow copy we replace all the references (even the nested ones), but keep the end (leaf) values the same. But actually it's just about creating a new object which has got exactly the same data structures under the hood. My first comment is confusing, would like to remove it.